# std::vector deleting duplicates and then deleting the same index in another vector

Tags: c++

I know of how to delete duplicates of a std vector with the STL as such

```
vec1.erase(std::unique(vec1.begin(), vec1.end()),vec1.end());
```

but what if i have a different `vec2` that is the same length as `vec1` and i wish to delete the same indexes that was removed in `vec1`? Such that if index 2 , 4 and 6 were removed in vec1 , the same would be removed in vec2

Comment: This removes duplicates only when they are consecutive. Do you sort your `vec1` before calling `unique` / `erase`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight in my case its not sorted but there are many consecutive duplicates , its a cdf of a weird distribution i can put a sample data set if you'd like

Comment: @pyCthon: Why not use `std::set`?

Comment: @JesseGood there are many operation's in the algorithm i'm following before this part that aren't preformed on both

Comment: @JesseGood I suppose i could convert them to `std::set` but won't that be less efficient?

Comment: @pyCthon: It depends. If the number of duplicates is large enough, a `std::set` might be more efficient. Or you could store the data in a `std::set` for some operations and then dump the data into a `std::vector` later, etc. However, you have to run tests to find out.

Comment: @JesseGood the size of each vector will range from 2^13 to 2^17 and the number of duplicates will be random(i'm not sure how to tell how many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to think of a different datastructure, perhaps `vector<pair<vec1_type, vec2_type>>`

But here's one way to do it (c++11)

```
std::vector<int> indices(vec1.size());
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
indices.erase(std::unique(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                          [&](int a, int b){ return vec1[a] == vec1[b]; }),
              indices.end());
auto vec1_iterator = vec1.begin();
auto vec2_iterator = vec2.begin();
for (int i : indices) {
  *vec1_iterator++ = vec1[i];
  *vec2_iterator++ = vec2[i];
}
vec1.erase(vec1_iterator, vec1.end());
vec2.erase(vec2_iterator, vec2.end());
```

Comment: this is a very nice way of doing it, sort of haskellish with the iota part, i've never seen that before, thank you for introducing it to me

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the original vector, then walk the two vectors in search of matching items, and erase from the parallel vector when you do not find a match:

```
vector<int> copy(vec1);
vec1.erase(std::unique(vec1.begin(), vec1.end()),vec1.end());
vector<string> pv = // your "parallel" vector
for (int i = 0 ; i != vec1.size() ; i++) {
    while (copy[i] != vec1[i]) {
        copy.erase(copy.begin()+i);
        pv.erase(pv.begin()+i);
    }    
}
```